# How to join two separate armatures?

Tags: animation

Does anybody know how to join two different armatures into one armature and blend multiple animations in it?

Comment: as user51642 says, ctrl J to join but make sure they don't have same bone names. The animations are not assigned to any armature in particular, so you will be able to use any animation for any armature

Comment: But then after joining it it has only one animation Jumping so the other Running animation disappear. So as I'm using Mixamo it is a bit harder..

Comment: all the animations are available in the Dopesheet > Action Editor mode, but of course each animation will only animate the bones that they are prepared to animate, you may need to bring some corrections. Also you can merge animations, I'm going to check this

Comment: you could copy paste the keyframes of a bone action into another action, but maybe the easiest way to merge 2 actions is to use the NLA editor and merge 2 NLA strips

Answer (score 1):

As user51642 says, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join your meshes and armatures, but make sure your 2 armatures don't have the same bone names, otherwise bones will automatically change names and won't be affected by the animations that are supposed to move them.

To merge 2 animations, you can either:

- In *Pose* mode, select the bones you want in armature A, copy their keyframes in the *Dopesheet* (*Action Editor* mode), select the same bones in armature B, paste the keyframes in the *Dopesheet*.
- Or use the *NLA Editor* to mix several strips into one action, as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmXdzHucPeE) by Ianscott.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight both armatures and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: This doesn't work either. Is there anyone who could show how to do it with example. With two different animations starting from different location seamlessly. A- Running B- Jumping. But jumping from position where A-Run stops. 

P.S 

I tried to examine NLA editor but there was not so many tutorials on my topic.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select all transforms. This makes sure all the locations/rotations/scaling are applied. Next, select one armature, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to select the other armature(s) and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. That should work.